# mootools sort of list

Tags: javascript, mootools

Hi I want to sort an list in mootools that look like this

  some data here
  some data here
  some data here
  some data here
  some data here
  some data here

IT is using FLOAT:LEFT property of css and fix width so it looks like

```
__________    ___________       __________
|ITEM  1 |    |   Item2  |      |Item 3   |
|________|    |__________|      |_________|

__________    ___________       __________
|ITEM  4 |    |   Item5  |      |Item 6   |
|________|    |__________|      |_________|
```

If i want to sort like 4th item interchanges with item 1 and item 2 with item 6 and item 3 with item 5
Can you guide me how do i do this? Using Mootools at RUntime!
and this change need to come from php array i.e. Need to be dynamic .Please help me to learn this

Comment: http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Sort - In any case, SO is not about what your requirements are - you are not hiring a developer. try to actually make an effort, produce some code, or even produce the dom / css on http://www.jsfiddle.net/ - not your business requirements. you can take these to freelancer.com :) also look at working with arrays, some plugins http://mootools.net/forge/browse?search=array and consider if you need Fx or just to change the order of elements. if so, all you need to do is create a new collection of items, iterate it and reinject reordered elements into the dom

Comment: Everyone needs a guide i tried finding solution am learning and creating my own website Fx.Sort i tried already it only works horizontally or vertically but i need hybrid of this
Will be nice if you can help

had i knew it i would had done it my friend

Comment: you are missing the point. a lot of people can take your post and go away and do it, if they had to. but they don't. unless somebody feels _very_ generous, you can't expect them to go, build the html, css and javascript prototypes for what you are doing. that's why you should at least make a JSFIDDLE (link above) with the html + css of your work and even the failed code of your attempts thus far. it makes it much easier to help people. also, you should mention mootools ver and be more specific when you coin your question - `item interchanges` is too ambiguous and doesn't reveal what you want.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Hi. Here is an example of what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/YJugE/2/</strike>

<strike>The main difference from the mootools demo is using a list to sort, not a set of divs</strike>

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="red sort">red</li>
        <li class="red sort">red</li>
        <li class="red sort">red</li>
        <li class="red sort">red</li>
        <li class="red sort">red</li>
        <li class="red sort">red</li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

<strike>You could get a set of divs to work the way you want, but you would have to do a lot more css work</strike>

As far as I can tell, Mootools does not support a setup like you are trying to do. On the Doc page for Fx.Sort, the only supported styles are Horizontal and Vertical, none of which for for what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I've played with swapping elements before, here's a jsfiddle that may give you ideas:

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/ZwMUH/

in a nutshell though - if you disregard the Fx side of things:

get a list of the divs into a html collection (array of sorts)
swap each pair or reorder it any way you like.
loop through it and inject the elements 1 by 1 into the parent in their new order.

that's about it. prototype to swap 2 array elements:

```
Array.implement({
    swap: function(x, y) {
        var t = this[x];
        this[x] = this[y];
        this[y] = t;
        return this;
    }
});
```

the rest is up to you.